# Passing Html DOM inside an element as an string to AngularJS controller

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, dom, angularjs-scope

I wanted to grab the Html DOM inside an element as an string to angular controller. I didn't find good resource online. I have following Html Code:

```
 <div class="form-group ng-controller="straightRunningBeltsCtrl"">
         <button class="btn btn-success btn-lg" ng-click="post()">Get Service Factor</button>

           <div id="pop-up"><h1>My content here!!</h1></div>
      </div>
```

And I have following JS code

```
angular.module('straightRunningBelts', [ ])
.controller('straightRunningBeltsCtrl', straightRunningBeltsCtrl)

function straightRunningBeltsCtrl($stateParams, $scope, $http,  $sce){
 $scope.post= function () {
 var template=$sce.trustAsHtml(angular.element(document.getElementById('pop-up')));//Results an error( $sce.trustAsHtml needs string input)
    }
```

Variable template needs to get value from DOM.  Right now, `angular.element(document.getElementById('pop-up')` returns object. I wanted to do sometime like JQuery Does by using `html()` function [here](http://api.jquery.com/html/). Any help or reference to it is welcomed.

Comment: why no angular.element("#pop-up") ??

Comment: @Vanojx1 that results into `"Error: [jqLite:nosel] Looking up elements via selectors is not supported by jqLite! See: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/angular.element"` error

Comment: seems that angular.element support the html() function look here at https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element

Comment: @Vanojx1 I saw that and I am not able to implement it yet!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To retrieve the HTML inside your DOM element, you can use `innerHTML`. In your case it would be

```
document.getElementById('pop-up').innerHTML
```

[**Working Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/XWftIro8DyWnaD0CMwWO?p=preview)

Comment: it results into `"Error: [$sce:itype] Attempted to trust a non-string value in a content requiring a string: Context: html"`!

Comment: @DineshDevkota Its working here http://plnkr.co/edit/XWftIro8DyWnaD0CMwWO?p=preview

Comment: Try alerting the template or try checking its value. It is undefined.

Comment: Okay, just plain JS worked. I was not thinking straight. Removed `$sce.trustAsHtml(angular.element(document.getElementById('pop-up')))` and replaced with `document.getElementById('pop-up').innerHTML`